# Is there a way to run compiled Scala code, from another Scala script?

Tags: scala, execution

I'm working on project Scala developed. I've written a Scala program, now I'm trying to execute this program from another Scala code. But I can't.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You need to add your compiled jar file to classpath of your new script and then import code from there using regular “import” keyword.

Comment: Any reason you can't use [ProcessBuilder](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/sys/process/ProcessBuilder.html)? `Seq("scala", "prog", "args").!!`